# AWS-EBS performance degrades after some time

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are using Postgresql as server on EBS with 1TB volume and the data write operations performance very well till 0.7M(6-7 lakh queries) operations after that the the write speed start degrading.

Queries which are taking 0.02 sec to complete starts taking 10-12 seconds.

**Disclaimer**: We are having a write heavy database with 26 tables which performs write operation in 26 different tables.

The problemis that, CPU usage in our case won't exceed 40% and RAM always have 1.5GB free memory.

We had performed following experiments:

1. Used 300GB gp2 volume with and without EBS-optimized instance.
2. Used 300GB volume with PIOPS(with 15000 IOPS) and without EBS-optimized instance.
3. Used 1TB gp2 volume with and without EBS optimizeed instance.
4. Used 1TB volume with EBS optimized instance and `io1`(PIOPS of 15000)

Experiment performed on `r3.large, 4 core, 30.5GB RAM` for EBS-optimized instances and `t2.medium, 2 core, 4GB RAM` with non-EBS optimized.

Is this a problem of Postgres or EBS?

Comment: Are you using an EBS optimized EC2 instance? What do the IOPS metrics look like on the EBS volume? Is it a gp2 EBS volume or an io1 EBS volume? It sounds like you are using a gp2 volume and burning through your burst IOPS credits and if so you probably need to switch to a provisioned IOPS (io1) EBS volume. You might also want to consider spreading your EBS IO across multiple volumes in a RAID configuration.

Comment: @MarkB update questions with all details about EBS volume(i.e. PIOPS and EBS-optimized instance) and yeah I have doubt with RAID that it will really improve my performance or not so didn't used that.

Comment: ' Rest volumes were attached with t2.micro, 2 core, 4GB RAM.' :-- please explain meaning of "Rest volumes".  And AFAIK, only t2.medium equip with 2 core 4GB RAM.

Comment: @mootmoot that is *Rest experiments done on t.micro, I had done some experiments on EBS-optimized instances(i.e. r3.xlarge) and rest experiments on Non-EBS optimized instance i.e. t2.micro. Thanks for correcting me

Comment: Do you mean you also launch t2.micro to run Postgresql to perform those test?  Once you run out of t2 CPU credit , it will be throttles. and will not exceed 40%.

Comment: Yes I ran with t2.medium not t2.micro and its CPU usage was varying between 5-60% and CPU idle time was varying between 40-95% and CPU I/O wait time was varying between 0.2-1%(I noticed this cpu usage from `top` command)

Comment: Putting heavy DBMS on t2 and perform benchmark is a bad idea. It is possible the CPU throttling causing the problem. After running out of CPU credits,  t2.medium will hit the baseline of 40% CPU : check this out : 
https://medium.com/@cuttenweiler/misunderstood-misfits-the-t2-instance-14ed3ec9a314#.fig7v8khj

Comment: If you insist on saving some cents, you should just bid for spot instance and try them out to proof you thesis.

Comment: I have some AWS credits remaining so I am trying the experiment with `c4.large` is it good enough or should I try something else?

Comment: I am not sure what you attempt to achieve. If you change instance type, you should tune the cache up to match the performance.  1GB EBS will give you 3 baseline IOPS. perhaps you should try allocate  4TB to get 12k iops first and proceed with non-t2 instance to see what happens. This maybe more feasible than simply go straight to PIOPS.

Comment: I just notice the maximum gp2 iops is 10,000. Maybe you can spread your db to two huge volume   e.g. 2.5 TB  x2 (15k iops)  and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem appears to be that after a certain amount of time, your write performance slows down.

There can be a couple of causes for this.

First, you will see this type of behavior when using T2 family instances - they are burstable, but taking advantage of additional performance available to T2s only lasts until you run out of credits - then the instance reverts to its default performance, and in practice that makes the instance almost unusable.  You can monitor T2 credit balance and credit use from either the EC2 monitor screen or CloudWatch.  That can help determine if credit exhaustion is contributing to the problem.

The other cause for this may be burstable EBS performance.  The general purpose SSD EBS volumes (gp2) supports bursts of up to 3000 IOPS.  Starting in Nov. 2016, [AWS has exposed this metric via Cloudwatch](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-burst-balance-metric-for-ec2s-general-purpose-ssd-gp2-volumes/).  So if you are doing a large amount of IO (which you would expect during a load test) you may be running into has used up its burst balance.

Once you determine the cause of your slowdowns (and it may be a combination of issues) you can determine the best way to resolve it.  A simple solution would be to use provisioned iops (io1) volumes for your testing.

Comment: Provisioned IOPS is old idea before SSD become mainsteam.   Today, consumer grade SSD like Samsung 850 EVO 1TB can easily churn out 20,000 IOPS, burst  to 90,000 IOPS.  This seems to be EBS roadmap to move over over-provisioning storage than playing with provisioned IOPS

Comment: @mootmoot:  Depending on your requirements, paying for PIOPS may be cheaper than over-provisioning.   I don't think consumer-grade SSDs have much in common with the AWS EBS infrastructure.

Comment: AWS only offer SSD backed EBS in July 2014. A single SSD can easily arrays of magnetic disk setup.   Consumer grade SSD IO example is just to show that you should move on to gp2. (AWS is using commercial grade SSD).

Comment: @mootmoot: As of 2017, AWS still offers both SSD (io1, gp2) and Magnetic (st1, sc1) storage options.  Regular magnetic storage is still available.  I would like to know why you think they are using commercial grade SSD - as far as I know, AWS has never revealed details of their storage devices.

Comment: AFAIK, commercial grade SSD  pricing is not that far compare to commercial grade SSD in year 2016.  OTH, commercial grade magnetic disk e.g. 15K RPM cost premium (magnetic disk will face its doom similar to floopy give way to thumbdive ). AS reminder, this is IT. New technology become better and cheaper. AWS just refuse to play old-IBM-day rent-seeking marketing in order to stay ahead of the competition. IMHO, tracking AWS technology pricing from time to time is a good idea.

Comment: By the way,  just answer your question of "commercial grade SSD". EBS basically is SAN that use SAS. SSD buffering to SAS is not as critical compare to magnetic disk that have seek high latency.  Perhaps this is the primary reason why IBM sold their magnetic disk business many years ago.